# Use the full Google Maps V3 API and all its features in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to convert my Google Maps V3 Web Apps to Google Apps Script. How do I use/load the full Maps V3 API into a Google Apps Script HTML file (GAS Web App)? The normal  tag method does not seem to work.

I also tried Google Loader, but no success.

Even URLFetch, but no luck so far.

This is for a "Standalone Script", published as a web app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As of December 2014](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#december_2014) the use of the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 is possible using the [IFRAME sandbox mode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/sandbox-mode) in Google Apps Script HtmlService. Publishing the following snippet as a web app and generate a public key in the Google Developer Console permitting `*.googleusercontent.com/*` as a browser referrer:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ui')
                    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

-- ui.html -- (From [Google Maps Dev. Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The loader does not yet work in HtmlService.

Comment: That is unfortunate as it seems that Google Apps Script Web Apps is the exact solution I am looking for. Any timeframe/plans on when a full featured Maps API will be accessible from GAS?  Is there a workaround?

Comment: There is not a workaround. Sometime in the not terribly distant future, but I can't promise specifics.

Comment: Is that future any closer now than it was then? Even with the native sandbox, I haven't been able to get this or other Google APIs to work.

Comment: @Fred did you ever get it figured out? I'm trying to load the maps JS API in a apps script HTML template and I'm getting 'object is not extensible' errors.

Comment: That's the error I'm getting as well. Using the Google JS API tries to modify the `google` object, which Caja/HtmlService blocks.