# Google apps script html service and loading the Google maps javascript api V3

Tags: javascript, html, service, maps, google-apps-script

This javascript code on the page won't show the map. any suggestions? Is it the Caja sanitizer thats blocking the execution? Thankx! Cor

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    \\To load the APIs. I have found this code on https://developers.google.com/loader/;
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   \\next load then specific API module with parameters and Callback
    function loadMaps(){
        google.load("maps", "3",{"callback" : mapsLoaded()}, sensor=false, key="AIzaSyBfB1qRhJJiHGFUNtI87yfTrVLx-C8YYp4");
      }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var geocoder;
      var map;
      function mapsLoaded() {
    //this is how far the code is executed;
        alert("br");
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.2989, 4.9219);
    //this alert does not show up;
        alert(latlng);
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
      }

    </script> 

    <body onload="loadMaps()">
      <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></div>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use the full Google Maps V3 API and all its features in Google Apps Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820188/use-the-full-google-maps-v3-api-and-all-its-features-in-google-apps-script)

Answer (score 0):

No Google APIs are supported by HtmlService/Caja yet. We are working hard on making that pass sanitization.

Comment: is this still the case? Getting JS errors like 'Can't add property maps, object is not extensible' when trying to load the maps JS API from an HtmlService template.

Comment: +Corey G:  Almost two years since your response, I have to ask again. Any news on supporting Google Maps JavaScript API v3 from Google Apps Script?

Comment: Sadly I can't say. I left the Apps Script team well over a year ago.