# Unable to render Google Maps in Dialog using App Script

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script

I am trying to render a Google Map in the dialog box when the user clicks Maps-> Pole Locations in the following [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/a/bluepoint.net.au/spreadsheets/d/17u4IeVrfuykwrYggmSapWn6XvdcOXd_rnALsHh4kDbU/edit#gid=1257729947)

The Map does not render.

App Script function

```
function renderPoleLocations(){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('render.html');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Pole Locations'); 
}
```

render.html is the file that gets called by the HTML service. I am expecting the map to render within this file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Geocoding service</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="panel">
      <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
      <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress();">
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's not supported and doesn't make it past the javascript sanitization

[Google apps script html service and loading the Google maps javascript api V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138360/google-apps-script-html-service-and-loading-the-google-maps-javascript-api-v3)